# Can Redisgraph return numbers and booleans instead of their string representation?

Tags: redis, cypher, redisgraph

I'm working with Redisgraph.

I have a node Person with three properties: name (string), age (number), isAlive (boolean).

If I store the age as number, without the quotes, it correctly store it as a number. So, if I query:

```
MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p
```

what I have is:

```
{ name: 'John', age: 30, isAlive: 'true' }
```

but there's a way to query and get real booleans?

What I want is:

```
{ name: 'John', age: 30, isAlive: true }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're querying RedisGraph using `redis-cli`. The RESP protocol that processes module replies only allows strings and integers as primitive data types that can be passed, so your request can't be accomplished through `redis-cli`.

All of the client libraries, however, will decode replies to their correct type. I'd recommend using one as an intermediary to interact with RedisGraph - https://oss.redis.com/redisgraph/clients/.

Comment: Thank you @sentientcabbage for your reply. Yes I'm currently using redisgraph.js as client for JavaScript, but it doesn't decode booleans. Do you suggest me to use one of the others JavaScript suggested clients?

Answer (score 0):

Redisgraph can return a compact format where the type of the values are included. In order to use this you need to pass the `--compact` flag (which also works in redis-cli):

```
GRAPH.QUERY demo "MATCH (a) RETURN a" --compact
```

Some client libraries takes advantage of this compact format in order to return the correct type. The type of value is returned as an integer:

```
typedef enum {
    PROPERTY_UNKNOWN = 0,
    PROPERTY_NULL = 1,
    PROPERTY_STRING = 2,
    PROPERTY_INTEGER = 3,
    PROPERTY_BOOLEAN = 4,
    PROPERTY_DOUBLE = 5,
} PropertyTypeUser;
```

You can read more about the compact format [here](https://redis.io/docs/stack/graph/design/client_spec/).